# UIWebView not seeing remote css updates

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that's pulling data from an external website. If I change the css on that website, my UIWebView doesn't see the changes. If I open the same url on mobile safari, it does. I have to delete the app and reinstall it for the changes to be seen. Is there some caching that's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: >> Can you add some code? Code where you are loading the url. A code tells a thousand words.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UIWebView caches some data.
To remove a cached response for a specific request, you can use the following code

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

There is another way by which you can remove cache for all requests, that is:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Let me know if this helps.. :)

Comment: I'll try this out and let everyone know.

Comment: Apologies, didn't get to try this out before i left town. i'm back and was wondering how can i tie this to a reload button? in my storyboard i ctrl-dragged a button to the webview and hit reload. But how can i intercept this programmatically to call this code?

Comment: Put that inside the reload button event. And also make the url request after execution of this code.